# Cassandra CQL: Batch select

Tags: php, cassandra, cql, cassandra-2.2, nosql

Hi I have following table in Cassandra:

```
* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
* Note:
* 'curr_pos' is always fixed, so we can put it into cluster key and order
* In each crawler iteration 'prev_pos', 'domain_*' are updated
* -------------------------------------------------------------------------
* Patterns:
* <domain_name3rd>.<domain_name2nd>.<domain_name1st>
* --------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS lp_registry.keyword_position (
    engine text,
    keyword text,
    updated timestamp,
    domain_name1st text,
    domain_name2nd text,
    domain_name3rd text,
    prev_pos int,
    curr_pos int,
    PRIMARY KEY ((engine, keyword), curr_pos)   
);
```

In the top-level application I have a lists with circa hundreds of keywords.

**What I need?**

For fixed engine and keyword list i want to select all domains and their position.

**Update**: The result given by application will be a NxM matrix for each engine, with N user defined keywords and M user defined domains. In each cell will be position of domain for specific keyword.

**What I am confused with?**

I need to post N selects depending on size of the list with keywords. In other words, I need iterate through keywords in the app and in the each iteration send select to DB.

I expect that N won't be greater than 100, but still i think that this is too many queries.

**My question**

Can I pack these selects into a single batch? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not really a problem of batch query but a problem with the design of your table.

If the query you're describing is a "core" query of your application then you should design the table in a way that this is a single query, *ie.* `engine` and `keyword` should be clustering keys and not partition keys.

To give more specific advice: how do you obtain the list of engines and keywords, is there some that is logically grouping them? That could be the partition key of your table.

Comment: Thank you. Lists of keywords and engines are user defined. Each use case has its own list. For these inputs the application will produce for each engine a matrix N x M .. of N rows - keywords and M columns - domains.  In each cell will be position of domain for specific keyword. As list of domains - columns - are as well user defined, I can't image way how to create such matrix in a single select.